# Change default window location on click of Browse button

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change the window location when our user clicks on browse button from our web page to upload any files. I will give you scenario - I have a Browse button on our html form, When users click one window popup comes, which location is by deafult "My Documents".

Actually i want to change this window popup location on click on Browse button , say I have a directory D:\My_Project, I want once my user click on Browse button to upload the file, window popup should take to this location and from here user can select file.

I want to do using Java script .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to specify where the browse window will open.

(Nor, on the WWW, is there any way to know if they will have a "My Documents", a "My_Profile", or a "D:\".)

Comment: As you are saying that, they are not any way to configure to open window popup to our own choice of directory, on click ob browse button from HTML form? Please explain?

Comment: @ Quentin , please explain why?

Comment: Correct. Because it doesn't make sense on the WWW where you have no idea what directory structures exist and because it is a security risk if the directory view opens somewhere unexpected.